# How to insert a first column to many files + how to convert unix time to normal time

Tags: shell, text-processing, date, perl

There are many-many files in a directory that has e.x.: the following content:

INPUT:

```
root    1324711901
sshd    1272725792
```

And I'm searching for a solution how to convert the content of the files to this:

OUTPUT1:

```
filenameXXX.txt root    1324711901
filenameXXX.txt sshd    1272725792
```

OUTPUT2:

```
filenameXXX.txt root    Sat Dec 24 08:31:41 CET 2011
filenameXXX.txt sshd    Sat May  1 16:56:32 CEST 2010
```

So two things needed in two phases: 

INPUT -> "filenameXXX.txt   " before the first column -> OUTPUT1

OUTPUT1 -> convert unix times to normal times -> OUTPUT2

How to do this using bash OR sed OR perl? [don't need in all only 1 is enough :D]

ehh..and I need it in two part [so two one-liner]:
 - INPUT to OUTPUT1
 - OUTPUT1 to OUTPUT2

Field separators are "\t"-s [tabs]!

Comment: Is the first field (that looks like usernames) guaranteed to not contain spaces?

Comment: no, it doesn't contain any spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer `gawk` for this:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' 'NF{$1=FILENAME OFS $1;$2=strftime("%c",$2)}1' filename.txt
```

Here is one `perl` alternative too:

```
perl -nae 'print$ARGV,"\t",$F[0],"\t".localtime($F[1]),"\n"' filename.txt
```

As you also asked about `bash`, here is what it could do:

```
while read -r who when; do
  readlink -n /proc/$$/fd/0
  echo -en "\t$who\t"
  date -d "@$when"
done < filename.txt
```

Regarding `sed`, its usage would be hard and the benefit would be insignificant as it is unable to tell the name of its input file and to convert date.

Comment: field separators are "tabs"

Comment: your a living GOD :) [question updated! sry!]

Comment: Answer updated too.

Comment: *@manatwork:* Thanks; a good answer!...I like that method of getting the filename from `fd/0`.. Will it *always* return the fully-qualified path?

Comment: @fered, sadly `man 5 proc` not mentions that. Other symlinks like `/dev/fd/0` and `/dev/stdin` usually point directly to `/proc/$$/fd/0`. Other symlinks like `/proc/self/fd/0` indirectly points to the same file: actually `/proc/self/` points to `/proc/$$/`. So many links in different places pointing to each other, would be hard to follow in case of relative links. So I would never expect to find relative links there. Of course, all these `/proc/` and `/dev/` related things are system specific in some aspects, may not apply exactly to Unix and BSD.